# How to get a most recent value group by year by using SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a `Company` model that `has_many` `Statement`.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statements
end
```

I want to get `statements` that have most latest `date` field grouped by `fiscal_year_end` field.

I implemented the function like this:

```
c = Company.first
c.statements.to_a.group_by{|s| s.fiscal_year_end }.map{|k,v| v.max_by(&:date) }
```

It works ok, but if possible I want to use ActiveRecord query(SQL), so that I don't need to load unnecessary instance to memory.

How can I write it by using SQL?

Comment: `Statement.order('date desc').group('fiscal_end_year')`

Comment: It doesn't work `has_many` relation. The code ends up with a error `column "statements.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: @ironsand which database your are using `mysql` or `PG`? in `PG` you can only select column by which you are grouping.

Comment: I'm using `PG`, I also tried ` c.statements.group(:id, :fiscal_year_end)`, but it didn't give me what I want. I searched by the error message, but I couldn't figure out how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.username, t.date, t.value
from MyTable t
inner join (
    select username, max(date) as MaxDate
    from MyTable
    group by username
) tm on t.username = tm.username and t.date = tm.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 2):

For these kinds of things, I find it helpful to get the raw SQL working first, and then translate it into ActiveRecord afterwards. It sounds like a textbook case of `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  fiscal_year_end, MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM    statements
WHERE   company_id = 1
GROUP BY fiscal_year_end
```

Now you can express that in ActiveRecord like so:

```
c = Company.first
c.statements.
  group(:fiscal_year_end).
  order(nil).   # might not be necessary, depending on your association and Rails version
  select("fiscal_year_end, MAX(date) AS max_date")
```

The reason for `order(nil)` is to prevent ActiveRecord from adding `ORDER BY id` to the query. Rails 4+ does this automatically. Since you aren't grouping by `id`, it will cause the error you're seeing. You could also `order(:fiscal_year_end)` if that is what you want.

That will give you a bunch of `Statement` objects. They will be read-only, and every attribute will be `nil` except for `fiscal_year_end` and the magically-present new field `max_date`. These instances don't represent specific statements, but statement "groups" from your query. So you can do something like this:

```
- @statements_by_fiscal_year_end.each do |s|
  %tr
    %td= s.fiscal_year_end
    %td= s.max_date
```

Note there is no n+1 query problem here, because you fetched everything you need in one query.

If you decide that you need more than just the max date, e.g. you want the *whole statement* with the latest date, then you should look at your options for the [greatest n per group problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/25534279). For raw SQL I like `LATERAL JOIN`, but the easiest approach to use with ActiveRecord is `DISTINCT ON`.

Oh one more tip: For debugging weird errors, I find it helpful to confirm what SQL ActiveRecord is trying to use. You can use `to_sql` to get that:

```
c = Company.first
puts c.statements.
  group(:fiscal_year_end).
  select("fiscal_year_end, MAX(date) AS max_date").
  to_sql
```

In that example, I'm leaving off `order(nil)` so you can see that ActiveRecord is adding an `ORDER BY` clause you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

for example you want to get all statements by start of the months you should use this

```
@companey = Company.first
@statements = @companey.statements.find(:all, :order => 'due_at, id', :limit => 50)
```

then group them as you want

```
@monthly_statements = @statements.group_by { |statement| t.due_at.beginning_of_month }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Bharat's answer you can do this type of query in Rails using `find_by_sql` in this way:

```
Statement.find_by_sql ["Select t.* from statements t INNER JOIN (
  SELECT fiscal_year_end, max(date) as MaxDate GROUP BY fiscal_year_end
  ) tm on t.fiscal_year_end = tm.fiscal_year_end AND
  t.created_at = tm.MaxDate WHERE t.company_id = ?", company.id]
```

Note the last where part to make sure the statements belong to a specific company instance, and that this is called from the class. I haven't tested this with the array form, but I believe you can turn this into a scope and use it like this:

```
# In Statement model
scope :latest_from_fiscal_year, lambda |enterprise_id| {
    find_by_sql[..., enterprise_id] # Query above
}

# Wherever you need these statements for a particular company
company = Company.find(params[:id])
latest_statements = Statement.latest_from_fiscal_year(company.id)
```

Note that if you somehow need all the latest statements for all companies then this most likely leave you with a N+1 queries problem. But that is a beast for another day.

Note: If anyone else has a way to have this query work on the association without using the last where part (`company.statements.latest_from_year` and such) let me know and I'll edit this, in my case in rails 3 it  just pulled em from the whole table without filtering.